# Is there a way to find out which table column is causing an error in conversion with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a simple MVC app which consumes an API of mine to register information inside an SQL Server DB through an entity framework DbContext.

I can register an entity from the app to the DB just fine. But whenever I try to retrieve it from the DB to show it in my app, I get a `System.InvalidCastException` thrown at me, and the message it carries isn't extremely informative, it just says "The specified conversion is not valid.". The exception is thrown when attempting to execute `context.MyTable.ToList()`.

I have reviewed my model, but I don't see any type mismatch, and I use fluentAPI to handle the conversion between `bool` and `bit`, so I doubt it's that field (I have a different app where the problem doesn't happen, and I use that method to handle bools)

This is the code for my table:

```
Create table Property(
    Id int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Description varchar(60) not null,
    SalesPrice decimal(18,2) not null,
    Building bit not null,
    ZoningClass varchar(1) not null,
    Profit decimal(18,2),
    ImgPath varchar(300)
)
```

Model:

```
public class Property
    {
        [Key]
        [DisplayName("Prop ID")]
        [Column("Id", TypeName="int")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Property Description")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description cannot be empty.")]
        [Column("Description", TypeName="varchar(60)")]
        [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot be over 60 characters.")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Sales price cannot be empty")]
        [Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage ="Sales price cannot be negative.")]
        [DisplayName("Sales Price ($)")]
        [Column("SalesPrice", TypeName ="decimal(18,2)")]
        public decimal SalesPrice { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Property has building.")]
        [Column("Building")]
        public bool Building { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Specify a Zoning class")]
        [DisplayName("Zoning Class")]
        [Column("ZoningClass", TypeName ="varchar(1)")]
        
        public string ZoningClass { get; set; }

        [Column("Profit", TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
        public decimal Profit { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Indicate Image Route")]
        [StringLength(300, ErrorMessage = "Route cannot be over 300 characters")]
        [Column("ImgPath", TypeName = "varchar(300)")]
        
        public string ImgPath { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller method which handles the registration into the DB:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(Property model)
    {
        model.Profit = 0;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            switch (model.ZoningClass)
            {
                case "A":
                    model.Profit = model.SalesPrice * (decimal)0.05;
                    break;
                case "B":
                    model.Profit = model.SalesPrice * (decimal)0.04;
                    break;
                case "C":
                    model.Profit = model.SalesPrice * (decimal)0.03;
                    break;
                default:
                    model.Profit = 0;
                    break;
            }
            //requestHandler simply sends an HTTP request to the API.
            var res = requestHandler.AddProperty(model);
            if(res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
                TempData["Created"] = "Client Created";
            }
            return View("CreateProperty", new Property());
        }
        return View("CreateProperty", model);
    }
```

and the DbContext itself

```
    public class PropertyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Property> Property { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=myserver;Database=mydb; User Id=myuser; Password=mypass;");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Property>().
            Property(p => p.Building).
            HasConversion(
                v => v ? 1 : 0,
                v => (v == 1)
            );
    }
}
```

So, there seems to be a correct correspondence between the fields in the model and the columns in the table. I don't see which one is causing the error, and debugging the application isn't helping me, since the exception itself isn't very readable to me.

Comment: There's an outstanding bug in SqlClient where it will fail to convert some `decimal` values.  See https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/95

Comment: I can't see `context.MyTable.ToList()` anywhere in the actual code you have posted. Can you post the method that is actually throwing the exception?

Comment: I didnt include it because thats really all it does, it opens the connection with a using statement and the context and then just executes `context.Property.ToList();`

Comment: So why do you have the conversion? A boolean auto-maps to a bit field, i.e. 0 or 1.

Comment: I was unaware of this implicit conversion and for a previous app I had similar issues. In that previous app, the issues ended up being caused by something else, but I still left the conversion there just in case. Regardless, that bit of code is valid fluent api code for handling value conversion, so it really shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Well, it *is* a problem. If I do this in EF core 5 (also mapping to a bit column) I get a similar error. You're counting on implicit conversion from int to bit, which isn't possible.

Comment: This isn't a conversion from int to bit, it's a conversion from bool to bit.
The first line in the expression is about the rule for converting from .net to SQL server, and its saying "If V is true, then assign it as 1, else as 0", V is a boolean value so it can only be true or false. The 2nd line is how .NET should convert the data coming from SQL Server, in this case it can only be 1 or 0, so it's saying "convert V to the result of comparing V to 1". It's a really simple piece of code.

Comment: But EF *reads* a `bit` value which has to be converted by an expression expecting `int`. Yes, that should work (I had the conversion backward). Still, somewhere in the query pipeline this seems to get blocked. I wouldn't fight it, just remove the conversion.

Comment: It's because EF still reads the bit value as a bool and it's the bool value that enters `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetByte(Int32 i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove has conversion. Never seen anybody used it

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Property>().
            Property(p => p.Building).
            HasConversion(
                v => v ? 1 : 0,
                v => (v == 1)
            );
```

if you need something special it is much better to put the code inside of { get; set};

You have too many relevant requirements too.  For example  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Sales price cannot be empty")]. It will never be empty since it is not nullable and so will never be triggered.
You can only use  [Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage ="Sales price cannot be empty and should be positive.")]. Or column names since they are the same as property names.

And according to a sql script the Profit column maybe null, IMHO property should be nullable too

```
public decimal? Profit { get; set; }
```

Comment: bit<>bool conversions are built-in to SqlClient: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings

Comment: Yes, you are right .  I don't see any sense to use it here. Especially if it causes problems

Comment: As I pointed out in the post: It's not the conversion, since I have another app using that exact bit of code and it executes fine for the same operation that is throwing the exception in this app.

Comment: Just try it. If you don't need it is better to remove it now and don' t use in the future.

Comment: It didn't do anything after removing it. I understand that this bit of code might be irrelevant, but it's also not the one causing the issue, this is valid syntax for handling a conversion with fluent api. My guess now is that the issue is happening because of the decimal multiplication happening in the controller. Its most likely changing the precision of the number.

Comment: @Dasph What about the attributes TypeName ="varchar(1)" for example. Where did you find it  and what is it for? I would start from removing all  attribute requierments and only after it is working to add them back one by one.

Comment: @Dasph And pls check your Profit column and propery too

Comment: Those 2 are specified in the table creation script I posted. I will change the size of the varchar for ZoningClass (Zoning class is just a letter category, it's obtained from the registration form), since I just realized that the n in varchar for SQL Server does not mean amount of characters but bytes stored. However, I also don't think this will be the cause of the issue, since I can store the model into the DB (meaning the DB is ok with it being a varchar(1), it's only 1 character). The problem is happening when receiving the entity from the Db

Comment: You have  only common columns, that the most applications have. The only difference that you have to many requirement attributes that are relevant and you don' t need them. It is hard to see properties between so many attributes

Answer (score -1):

In your DB, `Profit` can be null since you didn't set `not null`, so your property must be nullable. Change it to

```
public decimal? Profit { get; set; }
```